# how to display specific screen for first ever time the app has been launched

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to find a way in which i can detect the first ever time my app has been launched/used so i can display a set-up screen. After the first ever launch has happened and the set-up has been completed i would like the app to just default to my main screen.

Does anyone have any ways in which i could achieve this? Also, i would like the app to default to the main screen even if the app has been killed after the set-up has been completed once.

I'm new to iOS and was thinking of possibly using a plist to store a value which would be changed on the first ever launch? But i'm not sure, any help and advice would be much appreciated with any bit's of code that anyone would like to share.

Thanks

Comment: Could you not just store a db value that says setup is done and have it run only when that value is false? - does it need to be a screen or is it just code that runs on setup?

Comment: it has to show a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ValueForKey:@"FirstLaunched"] isEqualtostring:@"YES"]) // Not first Launch
    {
   self.window.rootViewController = Main Screen;
    }
    else //first Launch
    {
      self.window.rootViewController = ONE TIME SCREEN;
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"FirstLaunched"];
    }
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: i'll give it a go and will let you know soon. but looks like it is what im looking for or something i can work with. thanks

Comment: just trying to get the self.window.rootViewController line to work as it cannot see the view controllers i want it to show

Comment: @Fernando, can you post your code?

Comment: did you solved your problem?

Comment: i invited you to chat, did you get it?